# Struts Wildcard vs Tiles Wildcard NoSuchDefinitionException

Tags: java, struts2, wildcard, tiles

I use tiles in my Struts2 project to generate dynamically my layouts. The problem is, i have to many redundancies in my tiles.xml file. So i decided to use wildcard in tiles to resolve this issue.

[I read this tutorial](http://struts2.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Struts2/Tiles+2.2.2+Integration) and followed all the instructions. I used  maven to create my webapp. Please look at my config files.

When I call this link:

```
localhost/test -> it works
localhost/** -> it works
localhost/test2 -> it does not work anymore, so wildcard was not called
```

Please help me. I don't know how to solve this problem. Thank you!

1. pom.xml

   ```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                                    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId>projectName</groupId>
     <artifactId>tilesWildcard</artifactId>
     <packaging>war</packaging>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <name>tilesWildcard Maven Webapp</name>
     <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
           <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.8</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
           <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.8</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <build>
       <finalName>tilesWildcard</finalName>
     </build>
   </project>
   ```
2. src/main/resources/struts.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

   <struts>
       <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
       <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
       <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
       <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
       <package  name="basicstruts2"  namespace="" extends="tiles-default">
           <result-types>
               <result-type name="tiles" default="true" 
                            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
           </result-types>

           <action name="/**" >
               <result>{1}</result>
           </action>
       </package>
   </struts>
   ```
3. /WEB-INF/tiles.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
          "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
   <tiles-definitions>
       <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/template.jsp">
           <put-attribute name="title" value="Default Title"/>
           <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/header.jsp"/>
           <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/body.jsp"/>
           <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
       </definition>
       <definition name="test" extends="baseLayout">
           <put-attribute name="Test Title" value="Default Title"/>
       </definition>
       <definition name="package/*" extends="baseLayout">
           <put-attribute name="title" value="{1}" type="string"/>
       </definition>
       <definition name="" extends="baseLayout">
       </definition>
   </tiles-definitions>
   ```
4. Files structure

   ```
   /WEB-INF
     /tiles/body.jsp
     /tiles/footer.jsp
     /tiles/header.jsp
     /tiles/template.jsp
   ```

Comment: You do not have tiles definition for test2. Why it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the very late reply but you are calling : localhost/test2, but the tiles definition is "package/*" so you would need to call localhost/package/test2